# Get-WMIobject win32_ntlogevent - Newest 3 events

Tags: powershell, wmi, event-log

Is there a way to pull the most recent 3 error events from the System event log using Get-WMIObject and the win32_ntlogevent class?

```
$log = Get-WMIobject -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -class win32_ntlogevent -filter "(logfile='system') AND (type='error')"
```

I know that `Get-EventLog` has a `-Newest` option but I don't see anything like that with WMI

Comment: I'm curious... Why would you not use `Get-EventLog`? It is WAY faster than `Get-WMIObject` for this and it can do filter early on instead of getting all the thousands of records for you to sort later.

Comment: It doesn't support pulling from a remote computer with a separate credential

Comment: Then run it through `Invoke-Command`...

Comment: Can you run Invoke-Command without WinRM enabled?

Comment: Not that I can remember atm. Still, that's the best investment you could do. It would help you alot both now and later when it comes to powershell-scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

`$log | sort TimeGenerated | select -last 3`

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use WMI for this. Your approach will retrieve *all* error events from the remote host (which could take quite some time), and then discard all but the latest 3 once you have everything on the local host. Use [`Get-EventLog`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849834.aspx) and do the filtering at the source:

```psh
Get-EventLog -LogName 'System' -EntryType 'Error' -Newest 3
```

Comment: `Get-EventLog` requires remote registry service being started, and if policy says it's not at auto-start, `Get-Eventlog` fails miserably. `Get-WMIObject Win32_NTEventLog` works better.

Comment: On crippled Windows installations you will need to find workarounds, yes. And cope with their downsides, which I outlined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Wmi query supports limiting the results.

If you are desperate to use your command here is a most inefficient way of getting your expected output -

```
Get-WMIobject win32_ntlogevent -filter "(logfile='system') AND (type='error')" | select -first 3
```

Cheers,
G

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-EventLog -LogName 'System' -EntryType 'Error' -Newest 3
```

WMI is the far more efficient way,  and it returns the log name

`$dt = $cdt = Get-Date;$CUmonth = (get-date).adddays(-30);$eventId = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $SystemlogFqdn -LogName 'System' -EntryType 'Error','Warning' -After $CUmonth;"GetMethod:  $((New-TimeSpan $dt ($dt = get-date)).totalseconds)"`

GetMethod:  163.585552

`$dt = $cdt = Get-Date;PS C:\Users\User> $CUmonth = (get-date).adddays(-30);PS C:\Users\User> $eventID = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTLogEvent -ComputerName $SystemlogFqdn -filter "(logfile='system' AND Type <> 'Information' AND TimeWritten >= '$CUmonth')";PS C:\Users\User> "WMIMethod:  $((New-TimeSpan $dt ($dt = get-date)).totalseconds)"`

WMIMethod:  63.49941